# ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called- After fitting a SparsePCA

Tags: python, machine-learning, k-means, pca

After fitted a SparsePCA

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
from scipy.sparse import random as sparse_random
from sklearn.decomposition import SparsePCA
from sklearn.random_projection import sparse_random_matrix


pca_a = SparsePCA(n_components=2, random_state=0) #grafico 2d
pca_review = pca_a.fit(R.toarray())
```

I tried to Convert it into a DataFrame with the following code

```
pca_review_df = pd.DataFrame(data= pca_review, columns= ['Component1','Component2'])
pca_name_review = pd.concat([pca_review_df, validation[['Kmeans_cluster']]],axis=1)
```

But i´m getting the following error:

```
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

¿How can i fix it?

Comment: 1) what is `R`? 2) after which line does your error occur (the first or second dataframe creation in your example?

Comment: It happens in the second (dataframe creation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error occurs in the line

```
pca_review_df = pd.DataFrame(data= pca_review, columns= ['Component1','Component2'])
```

because `pca_review` is not an array, iterable, or dictionary, it's the `SparsePCA` object. To get the component values for your dataset, you need to transform the dataset by fitting and transforming (multiplying your data by your PCA projection matrix), like

```
pca_review = pca_a.fit_transform(R.toarray())
```

Then you can construct your dataframes.